# Find object jquery remove class of current object But not to remove other active object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
    <div class="tovar_color_select">
                    <p>Select color</p>
                     <?php $hn = new product();
                      $get_color = $hn->get_color_id_nullval($gg['id_product']);
                      while($fetch_color = mysql_fetch_array($get_color)){
                         ?>
                     <a class="color"  title="<?=$fetch_color[1]?>" 
onClick="chkcolor(this , <?=$gg['id_product']?> , <?=$fetch_color[0]?>)" 


style="background-color:<?=$fetch_color[2]?>" ></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
    function chkcolor(obj,p_id,clr_id){

            if($(obj).hasClass("active") )
            {
                $(obj).removeClass("active");
                $('.tovar_color_select a').removeClass("active");
            }


            else {

                $(obj).addClass('active');
            }

            }
```

Listen carefully about my query .I am already successfully in getting active class and also have remove active class of current object but I need to remain active other select DOM element which is select by user .Currently my code remove from all DOM element  active class.I just want remain select class active other DOM elements should have to removed from active class.if currently i have any syntax mistake you can mentioned but also you have give me some logical implementation of my query. Thanks in Advance for help

Comment: Need to see more code in order to know what user is selecting. We can't see how you call this function. Also not sure why so many params in function , the only one used seems to be `obj`

Comment: Now Surely you can view my whole code . @charlietfl

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're currently doing, but I think what you want to do is: `$('.tovar_color_select a').removeClass("active"); $(obj).addClass('active');` Remove all instances of class active and apply it to the currently clicked object.

Comment: So can you please explain it bit more . @mkaatman

Comment: Thanks I have solved my issue .Now i m going post my answer against my own question .Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplfied example: http://jsfiddle.net/a78xdey7/

html:

```
<ul class="listOfStuff">
    <li class="active">test</li>
    <li >test</li>
    <li >test</li>
    <li >test</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('li', $('.listOfStuff')).on('click', function(){
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chkcolor(obj,p_id,clr_id){

        if($('.tovar_color_select a').hasClass('active'))
        {

            $('.tovar_color_select a').removeClass("active");
            $(obj).addClass('active');
        }


        else {

            $(obj).addClass('active');
        }

        }
```

Now i Just have changed by one condition i m checking all objects or DOM elements which has active class then i just removed their active class and added active class to my current clicked DOM element or object.

Comment: This doesn't help at all but makes it more complicated. Think before you answer.